# ANDROID: slow response from server to my android app

Tags: android

We have developed an android application, which includes more than 45 server calls, that includes JSON parsing. We have hosted all our scripts on Godaddy server, now the problem is app runs smoothly here in India, but it won't work well in USA in our clients devices. They are using T-Mobile services and have good internet connections, but still there the app is unable to make request with server in time.

Also it's not a device related issue, as we are testing it on Samsung galaxy Tab 2&3, Samsung galaxy S, S2, S4 and also on Note 3. But this works well here in our country but not in our client's country USA

Comment: Please post your code and do you get any error logs?

Comment: there no error logs...just freezing

Comment: You really need to give some details about implementation. Are all of the calls being done at once? Are you using any networking libraries?

Answer (score 0):

use an async task so that it will have thread pooling. Too much simultaneous threads is bad. limit it to 4-5 threads at a time.